# valid SSL certificate verification reports as "Self-signed" and fails on ubuntu 14.04 for godaddy CA signed sites, despite root CAs being installed

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, certificates

System:   Ubuntu 14.04, `apt-upgrade`d to the latest.  openssl, ca-certificates, wget installed

Symptoms:

`wget https://api.xxx.io` will result in this error:

```
ERROR: cannot verify api.xxx.io's certificate, issued by '/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to api.xxx.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Where as `wget https://google.com` works fine.

`openssl s_client -connect api.xxx.io:443` results in this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
```

I attempted to reinstall godaddy's root certificate:

1. downloaded their ca cert crt bundle to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra`
2. ran `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and followd the prompts.

No luck.

also tried `c_rehash` with no luck.

This site gets successfully verified on an ubuntu 16 system.   Anything else I should try?

edit:
running `strace -e open openssl s_client -connect api.xxx.io:443` shows that it isn't even opening ca-certificates.crt:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

edit 2:
If I pass the CApath to openssl, it works.
`openssl s_client -connect api.xxx.io:443 -showcerts -CApath /etc/ssl/certs`

I've tried editing openssl.cnf and using the environment variable overrides and it still won't work otherwise.

edit3: updated the question with a single host rather than 2 different hosts with 2 different certs.

Comment: 14.04 has been EOL for 2 years. An expired public root CA?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ubuntu.com says EOL in April 2019.

Answer (score 1):

As editted much of your question is probably a crossdupe of https://superuser.com/questions/903247/ssl-root-ca-certificate-is-not-recognized-although-present-in-the-trust-store and https://serverfault.com/questions/607233/how-to-make-openssl-s-client-using-default-c .

I haven't confirmed Ubuntu source, but Ubuntu 14.04 nominally uses OpenSSL 1.0.1f which upstream has a bug that causes `s_client` (and some others) to not use the default truststore when you don't specify any `-CA{path,file}` options, and 16.04 uses 1.0.2g which has this fixed. (Apparently so did 16.10, but that was not LTS and is no longer supported.)

The config file is irrelevant; `s_client` doesn't use any config file settings other than the 'library-global' ones for ENGINE's and addedOID's, neither of which is relevant to this issue.

But note `www.tcell.io` (where your `wget` was redirected) and `api.tcell.io` (where you told `openssl s_client` to connect) are different machines. According to www.ssllabs.com/ssltest:

- `api.tcell.io` 52.8.231.1 correctly serves a GoDaddy-SecureG2 cert (serial 00c8c641d43c76286c) with the necessary chain certs (to be exact #2 and #3 are necessary; #4 is the root and is not necessary but is acceptable)
- `www.tcell.io` 13.57.73.170 serves the same cert but NOT the chain certs, in violation of the RFCs (which would reduce its grade except that it ALSO uses DH-1024 which already capped it at B). Without the chain certs `wget` was unable to verify the certificate. If the 'bundle' you installed added the chain certs to your truststore, which is not the way web-PKI is intended to operate, then `wget` using OpenSSL *is* able to build the chain and verify it.